# C++ Destructor - Explicit calls in an Inheritance context

Tags: c++, memory, destructor

I am not sure how pertinent my question is, but here it goes.

I know that we should only call the destructor explicitly when we allocated memory on the heap.

So let's say we have two classes: Animal and Dog which is a subclass on Animal.

```
    Animal a* = new Dog();
    //-------Do something here-----//
    a -> ~Animal();
```

Again, let us say that Animal contains several fields that are dynamically allocated and that the Dog class adds a couple more dynamically allocated fields.

Because Dog has more fields, calling the Animal destructor will result in memory leakage. Is this simply bad programming style or we can get a workaround?

I suppose we need to cast the pointer to the Dog type and then call the destructor, but I am unable to find any reference on how to do this correctly.

Comment: what you describe is the reason, why any class that is supposed to be subclassed should have a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> Because Dog has more fields, calling the Animal destructor will result in memory leakage.

That doesn't happen if `Animal`'s destructor is `virtual`.

Furthermore, you do not need to call `~Animal()`. The one exception is if you are writing your own allocator. Normally you call `delete a` instead.

Comment: For some reason, I have assumed that since virtual constructors aren't allowed, the destructors aren't allowed as well. I was obviously wrong.

Comment: Coming from a Java background, it is still a bit weird for me. By allocator, you mean a custom technique similar to malloc?

Comment: Yes -- almost nobody needs to write their own allocator. You have to use a special statement called a placement `new`.

Answer (score 3):

> I know that we should only call the destructor explicitly when we allocated memory on the heap.

Nope, nope, nope, nope, nope. You never, ever call a destructor explicitly except in very specific cases (placement new and unions are the two that I know of).

What you need to do here is call `delete` on your pointer. And as rlbond already stated, deleting through a base pointer is fine as long as the destructor of the base class is virtual.

Comment: Can you give me a concrete example where we should call the destructor explicitly? - Edited: Your edit answered my question.

Comment: @SlowTrout You *must* call the destructor explicitly if (a) you used *placement new* to construct the object inside a separately-managed storage, or (b) the object is the currently active member of an union that you're destroying.

Comment: The second case makes perfect sense. I need to further research the first case. Thank you very much for your answers.
So as a summary of my understanding: I only need to make sure I declare the destructor virtual and correctly set its behaviour and 'delete' will take care of the subsequent calls?

Comment: @SlowTrout `I need to further research the first case`  Hopefully that doesn't mean you'll use it (or better stated, abuse it).  There is hardly a reason, except in very specific cases, where you would use placement-new.

Comment: Knowing something cannot harm you, but yes, you're perfectly right. I did a bit of reading about it and it should be used for a very small subset of applications.